# Cannot update multiple rows in Sqlite database update command in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing a problem here. I am trying to bulk update my table i.e trying to update multiple rows in the database. The update is simple. I just need to set a column value to 1 which is actually used as a flag in the app. So I want to set the value to 1 and in the where clause I give the string array of all the ids where i want it to set. 
But the problem is that it gives me an "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range:" . However when a single value is provided either as string or an string array, the update works fine.

here is the query

```
db.update( tableName, cv, Z_ID + "=?", items );
```

where items is of type String[ ]

kindly tell me what am I missing?

regards

Fahad Ali Shaikh

Answer (score 4):

That is not going to work I believe based on the one line you gave.

If we look at the method call signature :

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

so:

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(); cv.put(colName, new Integer(1));

String[] items = new String []{String.valueOf(Z_ID)}

db.update( tableName, cv, Z_ID + "=?", items );
```

Does you code look something like this?

Your items array must match up with the where clause.  A different example would look something like this:

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(); cv.put(salesColName, new Integer(4534));

String whereClause = "band=? and album=?"; String whereArgs = new String [] { "U2", "Joshua Tree" };

db.update( tableName, cv, whereClause , whereArgs);
```